# executeBatch() runs good in local but do not working in remote server, no error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

```java
List<myVO> myList = someSource.getList(val);
Jnditemplate jndi = new Jnditemplate();

DataSource ds = jndi.lookup('java:comp/env/jdbc/demo')
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

String sql = 'INSERT INTO MYTABLE(NO, NAME, ADDRESS, NUMBER) values (sq.nextVal , ?, ?, ?)'

preparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)
try {
for(myVo my : myList) {
 ps.setName = my.getName();
 ps.setAddress = my.getAddress();
 ps.setNumber = my.getNumber();
 ps.addBatch();
 ps.clearStatement();
}

ps.executeBatch();
ps.close();
conn.commit();

} catch(exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code runs good in local, but in remote server, connection is OK but ps.executeBatch() does not work.

Local server and remote server share the same Oracle DB, only user is different.

No error log occurs.

Comment: First, try to insert a few items from `myList`. Use a regular for-loop for this so that you can try something like `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` See the results in remote. If that works, then you know it could probably be the size of the data. If that does not work, it's something else.

Comment: (edited) I already commit the records by 1000 cases; It works only partially in server. I'm so confused that why executeBatch() works randomly in my code only in remote server. I tried to insert only 20 data; it dosen't work so I think it is not the Java memory heap problem too.

Comment: Could you clarify? So you were able to insert 1000? But didn't work for 20? Also make sure if there are any ACL rules in the database, maybe blocking a `write` operation to the table or the entire DB

Comment: I noticed the problem; ora-12899 error occurs; but still confused that why remote server only have this error message in same DB. Thank you chris.

Answer (score 0):

I got the source of problem; the csv file I uploaded is crashed. I need to change the encoding. Thanks